# What is the correct way of setting up an abnt2 keyboard layout in preseed?

Tags: installation, preseed

I am creating a preseeding file for an automatic ubuntu 11.10 installation and I am having problems setting up the keyboard configuration. I need the keyboard to be configured as abnt2 so I added this to the file:

```
# Keyboard selection.
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string br
d-i keyboard-configuration/modelcode abnt2
```

But the keyboard is set as us. And the first time I log into the new installation I get an "incomplete language support error".

What is the correct way of setting up an abnt2 keyboard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you need all of

```
d-i     keyboard-configuration/variant select English (US)
d-i     console-keymaps-at/keymap select us
d-i     keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us
```

and possibly

```
console-setup/ask_detect=false console-setup/layoutcode=us keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap=us
```

on your append line of txt.cfg (or whatever isolinux config)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the correcting setting is:

```
d-i console-setup/model select Brazilian ABNT2
```